# finding the fitness function of genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I am attempting to find the set of solutions for the equation `a + 2b + 3c + 4d = 30` using Genetic Algorithms (GAs). Which fitness function and encoding scheme would be most suitable for this task?

I think the best encoding scheme would be Real Numbers, but the fitness function I tried

```
f(a,b,c,d)  = min(|a + 2b + 3c + 4d| - 30)
```

Comment: The fitness function in the question will try to solve the problem `a + 2b + 3c + 4d = 0`. I think you wanted the `- 30` inside the absolute value.